# Definition of exchangeable $\sigma$-algebra through $\sigma $-algebra generated by the measurable -and $n $-symmetric - maps.

Tags: probability-theory

In the book on probability by Achim Klenke that I am reading the *exchangeable* $\sigma $-algebra is defined differently than I have seen elswhere and I have trouble with showing that this definition leads to that for a family $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N } $ of random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb N } $ has the same distribution as $(X_{\pi(n)} )_{n \in \mathbb N } $ for a finte permutation $\pi $.

First a couple of definitions.

A map $F:\ E^{\mathbb {N } }\to E'$ is called $n $-symmetric if $F^{\pi } =F $ for all $\pi \in S(n) $, where we define $F^{\pi }(x)$ as $F(x_{\pi(1)},x_{\pi(2)},...)$. ($E, E'$ are supposed to be Polish spaces.)

Let $X=(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb {N } } $ be a stochastic process with values in $E $. For $n \in \mathbb {N } $ define $\mathcal {E }_n ':=\sigma(F:F:E^{\mathbb N } \to \mathbb R \ \text{is measurable and }n \text {-symmetric})$ and let $\mathcal E_n = X^{-1 }(\mathcal {E_n ' } )$

Now the *exchangeable* $\sigma $-algebra is defined as $\cap_{n=1 } ^{\infty } \mathcal E_n$, but my question concerns $\mathcal E_n $

It is claimed that $\mathcal E_n = \{\{X \in B \}:\{X \in B \}=\{X^{\pi }  \in B \}\}   $ for some measurable $B \subset E^{\mathbb N } $ (Here $X^{\pi } $ means $(X_{\pi (n) })_{n \in \mathbb N } $ )

**My question thus** is: how do I show that if $\{X \in B \} $ is in $\mathcal E_n $ then $\{X \in B \}=\{X^{\pi }  \in B \} $ and conversely if $\{X \in B \}=\{X^{\pi }  \in B \} $ for some measurable $B \subset E^{\mathbb N } $ then $\{X \in B \}$ is in $\mathcal E_n $?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

*I believe I have almost solved my own question.*

For any $\pi \in S(n) $ define $T_{\pi } \ :\mathcal E_n' \to \mathcal E_n '  \ , T(x_1,x_2,...)=(x_{\pi(1)},x_{\pi(2)},...)$, then for any $n $-symmetric and $\mathcal E_n' - \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ measurable F and any $\pi \in S(n) $ we have that $F=F  \circ T_{\pi }  $. Thus $T_{\pi } $ is $\mathcal E_n' - \mathcal E_n'$ measurable.

Now given any $\pi \in S(n) $ take anny $n $-symmetric and $\mathcal E_n' - \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ measurable F and then for any $C \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R) $ we have that $F^{-1} (C)=T_{\pi ^{-1 }} ^{-1 } \circ F^{-1 } (C)$ and as $T_{\pi ^{-1 }} ^{-1 }=T_{\pi } $ we have for sets of the form $F^{-1 } (C)$ that $T_{\pi }(F^{-1 }(C))=F^{-1 }(C) $

**I still have to prove that this holds for any $B \in \mathcal E_n'$ though!**